# Is it possible to run Carla simulator in Google Linux VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vulkan, carla, nomachine

I am trying to run Carla simulator in Google Linux VM instance (Ubuntu 20.4 with GPU NVIDIA Tesla P100 Virtual Workstation). I used NoMachine to remotely connect to the instance.

All the installation steps are done perfectly but when I run Carla simulator, it will show below error
[image]

I run the vulkaninfo command on NoMachine then an exception is thrown

> build/vulkan-tools-KEbD_A/vulkan-tools-1.2.131.1+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:477: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

However, if I run vulkaninfo command on SSH connection then it results correctly.

I guess that is because there is no physic display for Google VM instance so NoMachine cannot detect it (I even used NoMachine workstation version already).

So, I just wonder if it is possible to graphic display for Google Linux instance? Or is there any better way to do visualize remote connection rather than NoMachine? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you check the permissions and run gcloud auth login ?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure how it could help? I just read an article on Google Cloud, https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-a-virtual-gpu-accelerated-linux-workstation, it recommends to use  Teradici PCoIP for remote connection. I am thinking that it would be a problem. I am trying to get a Teradici subscription and try again.

Comment: Have you already installed the NVIDIA drivers? After you create an instance with one or more GPUs, your system requires device drivers so that your applications can access the device. [This guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu) shows the ways to install NVIDIA proprietary drivers on instances with public images.

Comment: yes, I did, I even can view youtube on the VM, but wasn't able to run Carla due to an error about Vulkan library. I guess the reason is that NoMachine was not able to detect a physical monitor.

Comment: Does nomachine use Xvfb? I believe Xvfb may not support vulkan as per [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631962/is-xvfb-with-mesa-19-2-compatible-with-vulkan).

Comment: Thank you @JudithGuzmán, you might be right. So, I tried to run Carla with -opengl option but it still did not work, it says "Cannot openGL context. Check that the drivers and hardware support at least OpenGL 4.3...". Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have check opengl version and it is 1.3, so weird since it is supposed to be 4.4 as specified on [Testla release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/pdf/tesla-release-notes-440-3301.pdf)

Comment: I think nomachine won't be useful for you. You could try installing  Parsec or Teradici as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with no machine and vulkan as per [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631962/is-xvfb-with-mesa-19-2-compatible-with-vulkan).

You could try using [Teradici for PCoIP](http://www.teradici.com/what-is-pcoip) as suggested in GCP's documentation for ["Creating a virtual GPU-accelerated Linux workstation"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-a-virtual-gpu-accelerated-linux-workstation). A Free trial period can be requested [here](http://connect.teradici.com/cas-trial).

Comment: I did not try Parsec yet but Teradici is for enterprise product/business only AFAI know. I just want to use it for study.

Comment: @phuongle Parsec could be an alternative for educative purposes. Remember you can sign up for Free Trial with Teradici by contacting a sales representative [here](http://connect.teradici.com/cas-trial).